# How to write two return statements?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a method that takes two integers which represent an interval. The method shall return the sum of the integers. The method shall return -1 íf the first integer is negative, or the second integer is smaller than the first. I don't understand how I'm supposed to do the return -1 statement. Should I make an if statement?

```
public static int sumRange(int i1, int i2){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = i1; i <= i2; i++){
        sum = i + sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: try and if statement and see what happens.

Comment: And hint: use names that mean something to human readers. i1 and i2 ... do not mean anything.

Comment: @GhostCat Good tip, will implement it thank you.

Comment: Not related to your question; you can remove your loop and just use the formula `int sum = (i2-i1+1)*(i1+i2)/2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the if condition:

```
    if (i1<0 || i2<i1){
      return -1;
    }
```

full code:

```
public static int sumRange(int i1, int i2){
    if (i1<0 || i2<i1){
      return -1;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = i1; i <= i2; i++){
        sum = i + sum;

    }
    return sum;


}
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now, I tried earlier with if (i1 = -1 || i2<i1){ But it was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You just return a -1 when the conditions are those.

```
public static int results(int a, int b) {

        //If the first number is negative or the second number is higher than first, returns -1
        if (a < 0 || b < a) {
            return -1;
        }

        int sum = 0; //In this variable you will store your sum
        //iterate from A until B and sum
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```